# Универсальный UserControl как обёртка для прикладных UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хочу создать универсальный UserControl, обёртку для прикладных UserControl.

Например: У меня есть задача создавать множество UserControl'ов для редактирования, все они похожи друг на друга, у каждого есть кнопка СОХРАНИТЬ и ОТМЕНИТЬ и т.д. Отличаются они содержанием Item свойства которого я редактирую.

Я хочу сделать что-то похожее

```
<!-- Вызывать универсальную форму редактирования -->
<editOf>
    <!-- Передавать редактируемый UserControl  -->
    <viewEditItem/>
</editOf>
```

EditOfViewModel планируется примерно такого содержания:

```
public class EditOfViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
        public void EditOfViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => 
            {
                //Сохраняем 
            });
        }


            private IItem _view;
            public IItem Item
            {
                get => _view;
                set
                {
                    if (Equals(value, _view)) return;
                    _view = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; set; } 
            public DelegateCommand CancelCommand { get; set; } 

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
```

Каждый viewEditItem будет содержать свой Item (который планируется редактировать) который будет наследоваться от IItem.

Подскажите как связать editOf с viewEditItem, я смотрю в сторону ContentControl но пока не понимаю как реализовать задуманное.

Comment: Посмотрите, например, стандартный шаблон `Label` или `Button`, там используется `ContentPresenter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас ViewModel единый для всех редактируемых элементов, то привязаться к нему можно только вот так.

1. Создаете свой универсальный контрол (StackPanel и кнопки это из вашего описания и для понимания работы смысловой нагрузки не несут):

```html
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp10.GenericControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Принять" />
            <Button Content="Отмена" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

2. Делаем свой контрол для редактирования:

```html
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp10.EditItemView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Я контрол для редактирования!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

3. На форме где вы планируете использовать контрол, размещаете свой универсальный компонет и в его ресурсах задаете связку (DataTemplate как раз определяет какой вложенный контро использовать для какого ViewModel):

```html
<local:GenericControl>
    <local:GenericControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:EditOfViewModel}">
            <local:EditItemView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </local:GenericControl.Resources>
</local:GenericControl>
```

4. Проверяете что все работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если у вас есть возможность завести для каждого ViewModel для редактирования потомка от вашего базового EditOfViewModel (в нем может вообще ничего не быть, просто класс, с новым именем и объявлением его потомком от EditOfViewModel), то привязку какой View показывать внутри вашего универсального контрола в соответствии к какому ViewModel, вы можете в отдельном файле ресурсов. Подробнее про этот подход можно посмотреть [здесь](https://losev-al.blogspot.com/2015/12/view-mvvm-2.html).